# understanding this JavaScript statement

Tags: javascript

I am looking at this function in a javascript file:

```
function V(a, b) {
    var e = d.isPlainObject(a.ajax) && a.ajax.dataSrc !== c ? a.ajax.dataSrc : a.AjaxDataProp;
    return "data" === e ? b.aadData || b[e] : "" !== e ? B(e)(b) : b
}
```

could someone please explain what the last statement with the return keyword is doing?
I am familiar with the ternary operator. But I don't understand this line.

I don't think that any background knowledge of the variables or the functions is needed to explain the logic of the statement.

Comment: specifically - what are you having a problem with?

Comment: e is "content" not data when I debug. b is an object that contains the property aaData but the function is returning undefined and the debugger complains that it can't read it's length property

Comment: That `B` in that return statement `B(e)(b)` must be a function that returns a function, which in turn is called with `b` as argument.

Comment: Those yoda conditions are annoying too.

Comment: @Andy that's your preference which many don't agree with though.

Comment: That's why it's _my_ preference. No-one has to agree with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write it out, so it's easy readable so when  e = "content"   B(e)(b) is returned

```
 if("data" === e) //You end-up here when (e == "data")
   return b.aadData || b[e];
 else {
    if("" !== e) //You end-up here when (e != "data" && e != "")
      return B(e)(b);  //B(e) returns a function which is invoked r_function(b)
    else   //You end-up here when (e == "")
      return b
 }
```

**My advice**: Don't use te .min.js libs when you are debugging. Most of the time you can use a javascript file which is not minimized/compressed and way easier to debug/read.

**Basics Conditional (ternary) Operator**

```
true ? "This goes out" : "This not"
false ? "This not" : "This goes out"
```

Comment: Thank you! it makes sense when you write it out like that!

Answer (score 2):

```
return "data" === e ? b.aadData || b[e] : "" !== e ? B(e)(b) : b
```

this is called [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), where:

> condition:

```
"data" === e
```

checks `e` var is equal to "data" and it's the same type of "data", so a string;

> if true:

```
b.aadData || b[e]
```

returns the OR condition between `b.aaDData` OR `b[e]`;

> if false:

```
"" !== e ? B(e)(b) : b
```

this is the same conditional (ternary) operator: if `e` var is different from "" it returns `B(e)(b)`, else it gives you `b`.

Comment: More commonly called ternary or conditional operator i believe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator